I need help streaming RTSP from camera ip
I use the ffmpeg library to stream rtsp stream from the camera using TCP method, but I have a problem that when using the ffmpeg library and live streaming, I encounter the phenomenon that vq=0kb causes the video to freeze, and when recording the video, the video is interrupted. Does anyone have any settings or ways to help me solve the above problem? Thank you every body.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
